# Empty function optimization in glolang compiler

Tags: go, compiler-optimization

Does golang compiler optimize empty functions?

I hope to remove debug log code line from main.go when building production

main.go

```golang
func main() {
  logging.DebugLog("hey %d", 123)
}
```

Debug mode,

```golang
// +build dev
package logging

import (
    "fmt"
)

func DebugLog(pattern string, args... interface{}) {
    msg := fmt.Sprintf(pattern, args...)
    fmt.Printf("debug: %s\n", msg)
}
```

Production mode,

```golang
// +build !dev
package logging

import (
    "fmt"
)

func DebugLog(pattern string, args... interface{}) {}
```

Does golang compiler remove DebugLog function line from main function in compile time? or just leave and executed in running time?

Comment: The compiler probably inlines the function.

Comment: This is hard to tell in general. Think of a call like `DebugLog("foo", f())`. If `f` has side effects at least the call to f cannot be be dropped. Such optimizations typically change with each compiler version. Peek at the generated assembly. Note that the function call in main cannot be dropped by the _compiler_ (albeit inlined) and I doubt the current linker would drop it. You really should inspect your generated executable.

Comment: Try using objdump tool https://golang.org/cmd/objdump/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer this detailed.

Answer is yes, at least some version of golang compiler.

### test bed

go version go1.13.15 linux/amd64

cat ./main.go

```
package main

import (
    "./fc"
)

func main() {
    fc.Dosome()
}
```

cat ./fc/funcdummy.go

```
// +build !dev

package fc

func Dosome() {
}
```

cat ./fc/func.go

```
// +build dev

package fc

import (
    "fmt"
)

func Dosome() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

```
go build -tags dev -o ./havetag ./main.go
go build -o ./notag ./main.go
go tool objdump -S ./notag  > ./dumpnotag
go tool objdump -S ./havetag  > ./dumphavetag
```

### result

grep 'Dosome' -A 5 -B 5 ./dumphavetag

```
  0x48cf69      483b6110        CMPQ 0x10(CX), SP   
  0x48cf6d      7670            JBE 0x48cfdf        
  0x48cf6f      4883ec58        SUBQ $0x58, SP      
  0x48cf73      48896c2450      MOVQ BP, 0x50(SP)   
  0x48cf78      488d6c2450      LEAQ 0x50(SP), BP   
    fc.Dosome()
  0x48cf7d      0f57c0          XORPS X0, X0        
    fmt.Println("hello world")
  0x48cf80      0f11442440      MOVUPS X0, 0x40(SP) 
  0x48cf85      488d0554120100      LEAQ 0x11254(IP), AX    
  0x48cf8c      4889442440      MOVQ AX, 0x40(SP)
```

grep 'Dosome' -A 5 -B 5 ./dumpnotag

```
//empty
```

So, we can see that, empty function is optimized, without more compile flags for golang compiler.

### more

I found this [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/4563) related, so you need modern version of go compile. And you can get what you what.

> We now do whole subtree inlining, and dead code elimination.